# hibernate fetch strategy when using one table per class hierarchy inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate

Hello
I am using the one table per class hierarchy inheritance mapping to legacy data as described here

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass

here is what my mapping roughly looks like

```
<class abstract="true" name="note" table="NOTES">
 <id name="id" type="long" column="NOTE_ID">
     <generator class="native"/>
 </id>
 <discriminator column="NOTE_TYPE" type="string"/>
 <property name="orderId" column="ORDER_ID"/>
 <property name="text" column="TEXT"/>
 <subclass name="PurchaseNote" discriminator-value="PUR" />
 <subclass name="CancelNote" discriminator-value="CAN" />
 <subclass name="RefundNote" discriminator-value="REF" />
</class>
```

There can be many subclasses of notes to each order id

The Notes are described as associations in a Order Class something like

```
<class name="order" table="ORDERS">
 <id name="id" type="long" column="ORDER_ID">
     <generator class="native"/>
 </id>
 .....
<set name="purchaseNotes">
    <key column="orderId" />
    <one-to-many class="PurchaseNote"/>
</set>
<set name="cancelNotes">
    <key column="orderId" />
    <one-to-many class="cancelNote"/>
</set>
<set name="refundNotes">
    <key column="orderId" />
    <one-to-many class="refundNote"/>
</set>

</class>
```

I can get the associated collections fetched by hibernate if I do the following.

1) Use a "Where" clause in the set definition in the order xml
or
2) Use a force="true" as part of the discriminator definition in the notes xml

I can also, in a DAO call through a hibernate session from a session factory, use the HQL 
"from RefundNote where orderId = ?"
or 
"from Note note where note.class = RefundNote and orderId = ?" to get a list of the correct RefundNote subclasses and populate the list in the Order class by using the setter on refundNotes.

All standard hibernate stuff?

Any of these methods will create the collections firing off 3 queries (one for each collection) to the same table. As the number of subclasses grows this seems ineffiecient....?

I've read lots but can't see any way that hibernate (through fetch strategies, join,subselect,etc) could minimise these calls to a singe db call and still populate my collections.....?

I can get all notes and iterate through in Java to build the collections through class.simpleName inspection but was wondering if I'm missing something hibernate will do.....?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to dig deep into the code to verify, but I suspect this is simply how Hibernate handles mapped associations like this - it's always going to make one database call per hydrated association.

An alternative approach is to have one mapped hibernate collection, Notes, and then have transient fields for refundNotes, etc.

In the getter for your specific types, iterate over the notes collection to find the specific notes of interest. In your setter, have it add to the general notes collection.

This way, hibernate will make the single query to fetch the notes, and you can operate on the hydrated objects as needed.